# Styling magnific-popup arrows

Tags: magnific-popup

How do I style magnific-popup's next and previous arrows with my own custom image spryte arrows?
I tried manipulating styles for .mfp-arrow, .mfp-arrow-left and .mfp-arrow-right classes but to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.mfp-arrow-left:after,
.mfp-arrow-left:before,
.mfp-arrow-right:after,
.mfp-arrow-right:before,
.mfp-a,
.mfp-b {
   }

button.mfp-arrow {
   }

button.mfp-arrow-left {
   }

button.mfp-arrow-right {
   }
```

This can help you a bit.